# Function to write class types into data frame columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to build out a function where I can specify column positions and class type.

Using the `iris` dataset it would look like this:

```
 magic_class_write <- function(df, col_nos, class_types ){

 fill in the blanks
}



library(tidyverse)

# This is how I do it now

glimpse(iris)

class(iris$Sepal.Length) <- "comma"
class(iris$Petal.Width)  <- "comma"

map(iris, class)


# This is how it will be done with the function
magic_class_write(df = iris, col_nos = c(1, 3), class_types = c("comma", "comma"))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `for` loop you could do:

```r
magic_class_write <- function(df, col_nos, class_types ){
  for (i in seq_along(col_nos)) {
    class(df[[col_nos[[i]]]]) <- class_types[[i]]
  }
  df
}

iris1 <- magic_class_write(df = iris, col_nos = c(1, 3), class_types = c("comma", "comma"))
lapply(iris1, class)
#> $Sepal.Length
#> [1] "comma"
#> 
#> $Sepal.Width
#> [1] "numeric"
#> 
#> $Petal.Length
#> [1] "comma"
#> 
#> $Petal.Width
#> [1] "numeric"
#> 
#> $Species
#> [1] "factor"
```

Comment: One of the benefits of using the `for` loop is not to do the `return` after the assignment

Answer (score 1):

Using `Map` :

```
magic_class_write <- function(df, col_nos, class_types ){
  df[col_nos] <- Map(`class<-`, df[col_nos], class_types)
  return(df)
}

result <- magic_class_write(iris, c(1, 3), c("comma", "comma"))
sapply(result, class)

#Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
#     "comma"    "numeric"      "comma"    "numeric"     "factor"
```